# How do you make a black play button overlay visible on light and dark backgrounds

Tags: overlay, video, button

I have a black 70% opacity play button that sites on top of videos.

On light backgrounds it is very clear but obviously on darker backgrounds it nearly vanishes. I would like it to be visible on dark backgrounds as well.

I'd like to maintain the transparency feel.
I do not want to use an outline because it wold be the only outlined item on the site.

[image]

Edit:
I ended up doing a combination of the suggestions.
I added a white glow and I added a semi transparent white circle behind the black one which filled in the triangle and had the same effect as adding the grey. Thanks fo ryour help with this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to keep the transparency, then at least make the icon itself solid, this will have enough contrast to work against the dark background - even if you can't see the outer transparent background.

Answer (score 3):

I would try it with some grey. So instead of 70% opacity with a black button, Try with some dark grey with a little less transparency.

You have to look for ways to get some white into it. Very transparent textures, gradients or very slight white noise might help also.

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a website why not use CSS to transition the effect between dark and light backgrounds?

Code the circle with something like:

```
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 200px;
height: 200px; 
}
```

Add a triangle with something like:

```
.arrow {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
border-left: 20px solid white;
}
```

if i recall use the `~` [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to generate a transition when you have a dark background

That's if you are doing this for a website but I know you didn't specify that.  Hope this helps.